# PHP Data Cache with TTL in Milliseconds or Microseconds (Yii)

Tags: php, caching

I am using the Yii framework for a site that will get a lot of hits (hopefully) because each client will be polling every 250 milliseconds.  I want to limit the hits to my database and cache the data, but it needs to be close to real time (about 250 milliseconds).  I noticed that the $expire parameter in CCache->set() takes an integer for seconds.  I tried to go directly to apc_store() and found the same issue.  Memcache seems to also define TTL in seconds.

Does anyone know of a PHP data cache that can work with TTL values less than 1 second or another workaround?

Comment: Four times a second? Then you will get a lot of hits for sure - and probably performance issues. This sounds more like you should be using websockets or switch to a bigger interval of 2 to 5 seconds.

Comment: Looked at websockets, but I need wide cross-browser support.  I know subsecond caching is probably not common (too many misses in most implementations) but with the granularity of our polling I need to keep that off of the database.  Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else who may be interested, I also found Yii's [Cache Dependencies](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#cache-dependency).  There is one called CExpressionDependency.  With this you can hack together a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redis](http://redis.io) has sub-second expiration. See https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/169.